# LED matrix won't light up properly

Tags: led, electronics

As you can see it won't light up correctly, why is it so?
Is it possible that there are some issues with common cathode or anode?

I tried using just that smaller one by itself, in a similar fashion to the way I set the big one up.

[image: Led matrixes/matrices]

[image]

[image]

datapin: GPIO 10,
clockpin: GPIO 11,
CS pin: GPIO 8,

3.3v into VCC
GND on GND

Comment: Schematic (or at least clear photos) of wiring? Code you're using? We're not magicians here; we can't guess as to what's wrong without at least a minimal amount of background on the situation.

Comment: You've got it connected backwards. Turn through 180°

Answer (score 0):

You've got the LED matrix upside down on the circuit board. Turn it through 180°

Comment: Didn't seem to work, i got even fewer LEDs lighting up :(